# Can't boot TWRP image using fastboot boot

Tags: fastboot

I'm trying to root my Moto Z3 Play. I'm on Windows 10, I have already unlocked the bootloader, however, I can't boot the `twrp.img`.

I got the `twrp.img` from here https://twrp.me/motorola/motorolamotoz3play.html and I downloaded the latest image `twrp-3.4.0-0-beckham.img`. I also have downloaded the latest adb and fastboot version.

This is what happens when I attempt to boot to the image:

```
C:\adb\platform-tools> adb -s ZY2266C9DH reboot bootloader
C:\adb\platform-tools> fastboot devices
ZY2266C9DH      fastboot
C:\adb\platform-tools> fastboot boot twrp.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
```

And won't continue past that point except sometimes it does this:

```
downloading 'boot.img'...
FAILED (status read failed (Too many links))
finished. total time: 528.539s
```

I have tried every USB port on my computer all with the same result. Is this be a USB incompatibility? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different computer that had USB 2.0 ports and it everything worked perfectly. I don't quite understand why but that's what I did if anyone else has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me a solution was change USB and first send:

```
fastboot reboot bootloader
```

then:

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

Answer (score 0):

For a while twrp 3.3.1-0 was the only img working for Beckham, give it shot might still be the case.
and try changing the twrp.img name to recovery.img